# How to drop congested connections in Netty 4

Tags: netty

Using Netty 4, how can I detect that data I write is being clogged up on my side of the connection and close the connection if the remote end can't keep up?

I was checking whether

> ChannelHandlerContext.channel.outboundByteBuffer.readableBytes >
>   MaxWriteBuffer

but with the latest Netty 4 version this now gives me an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: nextOutboundByteBuffer() called from
>   outside the eventLoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this from the EventLoop as otherwise it is not thread-safe.

So something like this:

```
ChannelHandlerContext ctx = ....
final Channel channel = ctx.channel();
channel.eventLoop().execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (channel.outboundByteBuffer.readableBytes() > MaxWriteBuffer) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does anybody knows how to do exactly this (detect if the connection is congested) in Netty 4.0.20 ? I can't find anything related to outboundByteBuffer in the recent netty versions (looks like it has been dropped after an early 4.0 release) and i have no clue by what it has been replaced.